# external with delayed does it's work in multithread?

Tags: delphi, winapi

If I declare one function like :

```
function Sample: BOOL; stdcall external ADVAPI32 delayed;
```

so with the `delayed` directive, and that **2 threads** call at **the same time** this function that was never loaded, it's will work correctly? so is the delayed compatible with multithread?

Comment: It will work correctly, yes